# Questions completely changed

Tags: discussion

Both [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578770/fx-ax-b-cx-d-find-a-b-c-d/578800) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579192/probability-question-dices/579222) the original poster seems to be trying to reuse questions, as the edited questions are almost completely different than the originals, which were already answered.  Can someone with the necessary powers revert the question edits and contact the OPs (from a previous thread that seems to be the right thing to do)?

Comment: I have reverted them.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks.

Comment: For future reference --- I think the way to handle this is to flag the question for moderator attention. Lots of us can revert, but only a moderator can give the author a good talking-to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> For future reference—I think the way to handle this is to flag the question for moderator attention. Lots of us can revert, but only a moderator can give the author a good talking-to.

–[Gerry Myerson Nov 26 at 6:07](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/questions-completely-changed?cb=1#comment45944_11785)

Comment: Truly a quote for the ages.

Comment: @DanielRust ... and an answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @DanielRust, when I extract others' comments to make a CW post, I want it to be clear to all that they are not mine.

Comment: @dfeuer: BTW you can get a link to a particular comment by right-clicking the time-stamp.